# How can I get an animation to play in the order of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im new to programming and making the infamous Simon says game but I'm having trouble getting the computer generated sequence to animate in the order of the array.

I wanted to have a function that both wiped the previous sequence (assuming the game has started) and creates a new one while animating the buttons in the order of new array. I tried a few different methods but their outputs only confused me more.

```
var pattern       = []
var userPattern   = [];
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var started       = false
var level         = 0;

function nextSequence() {
  pattern     = [];
  userPattern = [];
  while (pattern.length < 4) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    pattern.push(randomColour);
  }

  /*Method 1*/
  for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + pattern[i]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
    }, 500 * (i + 1));
  }

  /*Mehtod 2*/
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[0]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 500);
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[1]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 1000);
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[2]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 1500);
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[3]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 2000);


  $("h1").html("Level" + " " + level);
  level++;
  console.log(pattern)
}
```

The first method doesn't play the animation at all and the second plays the animations simultaneously  completely disregaurding the setTimeout function. Method 2 also returns a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object' directed at all 4 lines of code.

Comment: In method 2 you forgot you need to pass a function to setTimeout, you just passed a line of code, which gets executed right away.

Comment: Also, you should not clear `pattern = [];` (reset to empty array) inside the `nextSequence` function. The game should always remember the randomly generated color until the game ends. Why do you use `while (pattern.length < 4) {` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first method you are passing a function as parameter to the `setTimeout` which is fine, but by the time the `i` in the function gets evaluated it is already `i = 4`.

The way to overcome the late evaluation of the `i` is to pass a copy of it that will live inside a function (IIFE). Also the rest of your code will live inside that function, where `i` is what was meant to be when passed to it as argument.

```js
/*Method 1*/
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  (function(i) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + pattern[i]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
    }, 500 * (i + 1));
    
  })(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the response. If its not too much could you explain why doing this fixes the bug?

Comment: for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: the more modern way would be `for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {` - then you don't need the IIFE

Comment: understanding this is a good exercise. i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value of `i` is not what you expect when the setTimeout triggers its function.  Just declare it using `let`.

```js
var pattern       = []
var userPattern   = [];
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var started       = false
var level         = 0;

function nextSequence() {
  pattern     = [];
  userPattern = [];
  while (pattern.length < 4) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    pattern.push(randomColour);
  }

  /*Method 1*/
  for (let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + pattern[i]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
    }, 500 * (i + 1));
  }

  /*Mehtod 2*/
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[0]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 500);
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[1]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 1000);
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[2]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 1500);
  // setTimeout($("." + pattern[3]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200), 2000);


  $("h1").html("Level" + " " + level);
  level++;
  console.log(pattern)
}

nextSequence();
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: darkred;
}
.blue {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.green {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='red'>red</div>
<div class='blue'>blue</div>
<div class='green'>green</div>
<div class='yellow'>yellow</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why declaring i with let is able to fix the problem? I'm been trying to understand but I'm lost.

Comment: @jaredonnell `let` variables are `block scoped` - therefore the `i` will be correct

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the scope of `i` in `for(i = 0;...`

It's a global for a start, which should be avoided

Making it `for(let i = 0; ...` will ensure that `i` is the correct value for the setTimeout delay

However: I think using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
and [jQuery.delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)
and [jQuery.promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) provides much cleaner looking code;

```js
var pattern       = []
var userPattern   = [];
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var started       = false
var level         = 0;

function nextSequence() {
  pattern     = [];
  userPattern = [];
  while (pattern.length < 4) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    pattern.push(randomColour);
  }

  pattern.reduce(async (p, button) => {
    await p;
    await $(`.${button}`).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).delay(100).promise();
  }, Promise.resolve());
  
  $("h1").html("Level" + " " + level);
  level++;
  console.log(pattern)
}

nextSequence();
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: darkred;
}
.blue {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.green {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
<div class='red'>red</div>
<div class='blue'>blue</div>
<div class='green'>green</div>
<div class='yellow'>yellow</div>
```